Mediapipe Hand Landmark Detection How to remove Firework in Background when Thumbs up
I recently did a project on detecting Landmarks with Mediapipe. The Problem is when I do a thumbs up in the camera media pipe somehow detects it and adds a firework in the background. I don't know why media pipe is doing this. How can I disable it?
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.framework.formats import landmark_pb2
import cv2

mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vid.set(3, 515) #set height
vid.set(4, 515) #set width

while(True):
    ret, frame = vid.read()



    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = mp_hands.Hands().process(frame)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
        for hand_landmarks in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, hand_landmarks, connections=mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('e'):
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()





I don't know why it is doing it

... what? show us that.

It is likely that the fireworks have nothing to do with mediapipe. It is probably due to your operating system like on macos when you do the thumbs up it will add a thumbs up bubble automatically (if you have the setting enabled).
If the problem is still consisting can you provide more information like images etc.
